COM port not showing up in an app on Windows 11
I bought a laptop with Windows 11 Home, which I intend to use with my drone. The drone's flight controller connects to the laptop via USB and presents as a COM port in the drone's software (Mission Planner).
The problem is that the COM port does not show up in the drone's software.
Device Manager did not show Ports section, so I used Action/Add legacy hardware,
I tried the standard/communications port, which shows a warning with Error Code 34 when installation is done. I then tried a few other options, but all fail to install.
Powershell Get-PnpDevice shows the COM port with status "Error" and device manager shows the same error code 34 - "Windows cannot determine the settings for this device"
I also attempted to manually choose a config in Device Manager/COM port/Resources, but that only changes the error message to something like "device does not exist"

Have you installed the necessary drivers for this device?  Most USB devices that emulate a COM device require drivers.

@Ramhound installed them in all sorts of order - before and after adding com port from device manager. Reinstalled Windows 11 to upgrade to pro, and then repeated the whole set of attempts. I start wondering if it's possible to have a laptop that doesn't support it - as unlikely as that sounds
